# Finding minima / minimum curve in ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I have a bunch of data `trialstuff` corresponding to `{x,y,z}`, which I put [here](https://pastebin.com/mg5GYCyb).

I am plotting a graph of it:

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[trialstuff, 1], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

which gives me this:

[image]

where I wrote by hand the "line" which looks like the minima.

1) Is there a way I can find the position in the xy plane of the minimum?

2) If I know the minimum of zero, can I "solve" the equation to find where in the xy plabe the ListPlot3D is zero?

--

**EDIT after kglr answer**

With [this data](https://pastebin.com/ttWifdjV) and this code:

```
iF = Interpolation[Join @@ trialstuff];
pnt = Flatten[{{x, y} /. #[[2]], #[[1]]}] &@
  NMinimize[{iF[x, y], 1 <= x <= Sqrt[30], 100 <= y <= 400}, {x, y}]
Show[Plot3D[iF[x, y], {x, 1.1, Sqrt[30] - 0.1}, {y, 101, 399}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", 
  MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, 
    ConditionalExpression[Derivative[1, 0][iF][#, #2], 
      Derivative[2, 0][iF][#, #2] > 0] &, 
    ConditionalExpression[Derivative[0, 1][iF][#, #2], 
      Derivative[0, 2][iF][#, #2] > 0] &}, 
  Mesh -> {{3.1622776600251727`}, {228.06175994426033`}, {0}, {0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Magenta, Green, Directive[Red, Thick], 
    Directive[Yellow, Thick]}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   LineLegend[{Magenta, Green, Directive[Red, Thick], 
     Directive[Yellow, Thick]}, {StringForm["{``, y, iF[``, y]}", 
      NumberForm[pnt[[1]], 4], NumberForm[pnt[[1]], 4]], 
     StringForm["{x, ``, iF[x, ``]}", NumberForm[pnt[[2]], 4], 
      NumberForm[pnt[[2]], 4]], 
     StringForm["{``, y, iF[``, y]}", Superscript[x, "*"][y], 
      Superscript[x, "*"][y]], 
     StringForm["{x, ``, iF[x, ``]}", Superscript[y, "*"][x], 
      Superscript[y, "*"][x]]}]], 
 Graphics3D[{Orange, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[pnt]}]]
```

I get this picture:

[image]

What are the other random mesh lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
iF = Interpolation[Join @@ data]; 
pnt = Flatten[{{x, y} /. #[[2]], #[[1]]}] &@
  NMinimize[{iF[x, y], 1 <= x <= 5, 100 <= y <= 500}, {x, y}]
```

> {3.19945, 206.337, 811.46}

```
Show[Plot3D[iF[x, y], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 100, 300}, BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
  MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, 
    ConditionalExpression[Derivative[1, 0][iF][#, #2], 
      Derivative[2, 0][iF][#, #2] > 0] &, 
    ConditionalExpression[Derivative[0, 1][iF][#, #2], 
      Derivative[0, 2][iF][#, #2] > 0] &}, 
  Mesh -> {{3.199454}, {206.337}, {0}, {0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Magenta, Green, Directive[Red, Thick],  Directive[Yellow, Thick]}, 
  PlotLegends ->  LineLegend[{Magenta, Green, Directive[Red, Thick], 
     Directive[Yellow, Thick]}, 
   {StringForm["{``, y, iF[``, y]}", NumberForm[pnt[[1]], 4], NumberForm[pnt[[1]], 4]], 
    StringForm["{x, ``, iF[x, ``]}", NumberForm[pnt[[2]], 4],  NumberForm[pnt[[2]], 4]],
    StringForm["{``, y, iF[``, y]}", Superscript[x, "*"][y], Superscript[x, "*"][y]], 
    StringForm["{x, ``, iF[x, ``]}", Superscript[y, "*"][x],  Superscript[y, "*"][x]]}]], 
 Graphics3D[{Orange, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[pnt]}]]
```

[image]

where $x^*(y) = ArgMin_x \  iF(x,y)$ and $y^*(x) = ArgMin_y \  iF(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks this is great. Just for me to understand. What exactly is the red line and what are you specifying in the MeshFunctions with the derivatives?

Comment: @SuperCiocia, the red line is the locus of  minima of `iF[x,y]` with respect to `x` for given `y`, the yellow line the locus of  minima of `iF[x,y]` with respect to `y` for given `x`. I added a legend.

Comment: Thanks this is great. ON my plot though there are some other random yellow and red lines that appear for the mesh. Is there a way I can post a picture of what I mean on a comment?

Comment: @SuperCiocia, you can update your question with the issue and related picture.

Comment: I added an edit, thanks.

Comment: @SuperCiocia, the code works in version 9. In version 11.3 (Wolfram Cloud) I also  get the extra yellow lines. Can you check if using `PlotPoints->100` and `MaxRecursion ->5` helps?

Comment: I tried both options, even going higher in Points and Recursion, still same plot.

Answer (score 2):

The minima curve is to be refined but this is a start:

```
takeXSlicesMinima[data_List] := With[{xValues = data[[All, 1]]},
   Table[
    First@TakeSmallestBy[Select[data, #[[1]] == xValue &], Last, 1],
    {xValue, DeleteDuplicates@xValues}
    ]
   ];

takeYSlicesMinima[data_List] := With[{yValues = data[[All, 2]]},
   Table[
    First@TakeSmallestBy[Select[data, #[[2]] == yValue &], Last, 1],
    {yValue, DeleteDuplicates@yValues}
    ]
   ];

With[{data = Flatten[trialstuff, 1]},
 With[{minimaCurvePoints = takeYSlicesMinima@data},
  Show[
   ListPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"],
   Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize@0.02,
     Point@minimaCurvePoints,
     Line@minimaCurvePoints
     }]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

You probably only need one of the two functions defined above, depending on whether you want to take the minima using X or Y slices.